resolve module name in git submodule foreach in a PowerShell script
To simplify the problem, I have in a PowerShell script something like this:
param (
    [string]$TAG
)
git submodule foreach --recursive " echo `"$TAG on $name`" "

The problem is $name is not resolved at script execution. I need a solution where both $TAG and $name are resolved. I mention this because I had such a problem with a bash script and I encountered many solutions were one or another was not resolved.

The likeliest explanation is that you haven't defined $name anywhere :) Where is it supposed to get its value from? If you want to pass $name to git.exe without PowerShell expanding it ahead of time, use a backtick to escape the dollar sign: " echo `"$TAG on `$name`" "

$name supposed to be module name, the one transmitted from submodule foreach

I suspect your problem is your quoting. See here where the command's variable is wrapped in only simple single quotes: git submodule foreach 'echo $sm_path \git rev-parse HEAD`'-- you are mixing thegitvar$namewith the powershell var$TAG`.

@Gigi Then as I said you need to prevent expansion of $name before the string is passed to git.exe: git submodule foreach --recursive " echo `"$TAG on `$name`" "
